# I think the problem this site has is a lack of experts

Tags: discussion

There are some really good questions being asked here.

However I'm noticing that a lot of questions don't have answers, or only have one answer.

How can we attract more expert users here?

Answer (score 4):

I tend not to agree with the OP.  Experts would be lured in by other experts (but here we have the "chicken-or-egg" issue), *or* by *graduate-students-level* questions -questions that are advanced and sophisticated enough, and closer to scientific papers and issues and actual research, so that they would trigger the interest of experts, mixed with a teaching desire (if any).

And this subset of questions, graduate-level ones, is the one we lack the most: We mostly have people trying to understand the economics of their life or society (essentially asking questions that are inherently very complex, and so very difficult to answer *scientifically* in a Q&A site), or undergraduate students asking mostly trivial theoretical questions.

What needs to be "targeted" is Master students and comparable.